# How to compute that the volume of $Z(\mathbb{A})\backslash \frak{S}$ for a Siegel set is finite?

Tags: algebraic-groups, automorphic-forms, adeles

I found it quite hard to find a complete reference for the (adelic) reduction theory of algebraic groups used in automorphic representations. I want to show that for $G=GL(n)$ over a number field $F$, a standard Siegel set $\mathfrak{S}$ has finite volume modulo the action of the center $Z(\mathbb{A})$.

To be precise, the setting is as follows: $P$ is the standard minimal parabolic of upper triangular matrices in $GL(n)$, $N$ its unipotent radical, and $T$ the diagonal subgroup (a standard maximal torus as well as the Levi of $P$). Denote by $\alpha_i$ the simple root $\alpha_i(t)=t_{i,i}/t_{i+1,i+1}$ for $t=diag\{t_1,...,t_n\}\in T$. In the adelic setting, a Siegel set of $G$ is defined as follows.

First we let $K_\mathbb{A}$ be the standard maximal compact subgroup of $G_\mathbb{A}$. Choose a compact set $C\in N(\mathbb{A})$, and a positive real number $a$. Define a Siegel set to be:
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathfrak{S} &=\mathfrak{S}_{a, C}^{P} \\
&=\left\{g=n t k: n \in C, t \in T_{\mathbb{A}}, k \in K_{\mathbb{A}},\left|\alpha_{i}(t)\right| \geq a \text { for } 1 \leq i<n\right\}.
\end{aligned}$$

O.K. Then one can prove that there exists a Siegel set (large enough), such that $G_F \mathfrak{S}=G_\mathbb{A}$ (the proof is quite nontrivial as I know, so I just accept it). Next, one can use the finiteness of the volume $Z(\mathbb{A})\backslash \frak{S}$ in $Z(\mathbb{A})\backslash G_\mathbb{A}$ to show the finiteness of the volume of the adelic automorphic quotient $Z(\mathbb{A})G_F\backslash G_\mathbb{A}$.

I'm stuck here. I have no idea how to work with this finiteness statement. Maybe to be more concrete, I have no idea how to play with the invariant measures on these adelic spaces. I want to ask for some help or hint related to this computation, or any reference would be very helpful. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  At one place it looks like you want to know how to bound volumes of Siegel sets and another it sounds like you are okay with this.  BTW have you checked Paul Garrett's vignettes?  I thought he explained  such things.

Comment: @Kimball I just want to ask how to prove the finiteness (calculation with the corresponding measures) :) I tried to find what I need in Paul’s vignettes, but I didn’t succeed.